# how to break GNU Make shell function call to multiple line

Tags: makefile

Here is the correct code, but it is very long

```
$(shell if [ ! -f .oldmodel ] || [ "$(MODEL)" != `cat .oldmodel` ] ; then echo $(MODEL) > .oldmodel ; fi )
```

I tried

```
$(shell if [ ! -f .oldmodel ] || [ "$(MODEL)" != `cat .oldmodel` ] ; \
    then echo $(MODEL) > .oldmodel ; fi )
```

But There is a error

> common.mak:21: *** missing separator.  Stop.

the strange thing is that the .oldmodel is generated, and it's content is right, the next time call make, no error anymore.

Can anyone explain this.

Comment: I asked a wrong question, GNU Make can support multiple line, the wrong is because $(shell xxx) output something, and GNU Make treat it as the content of Makefile, so the correct code should be $(info $(shell xxx)) or _x := $(shell xxx) or don't output anything at shell call

Comment: It looks like you are trying to achieve something in a wrong way. You are generating a file, so you need to write a rule for that.

Comment: @igagis I want this action execute always, if i use a rule, then I need to execute that rule explicitly.

Comment: where do you use the `.oldmodel` file afterwards?

Comment: I will read it at Makefile `MODEL := $(shell cat $(TOP_DIR)/.oldmodel)`, so when I build next time, I don't input MODEL again, the first time I should `make MODEL=XXX uboot`

Comment: And where do you use `$(TARGETS_DIR)/$(MODEL)/` directory? I suppose in some rule?

Comment: yes, used in some rule

Comment: Have you considered putting `MODEL := ...` in `.oldmodel`? That way your makefile can have a line `-include $(TOP_DIR).oldmodel`, and a rule `$(TOP_DIR).oldmodel: ...`

Comment: I just cut and paste that (but put the `$(info ...)` around it) into a makefile, and it worked without the warning.   What does MODEL resolve to?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to achieve something in a wrong way. Consider the following solution:

```
ifeq ($(MODEL),)
    MODEL := $(shell cat .oldmodel 2>/dev/null)
endif

stuff_to_do: \.oldmodel
    mkdir -p $(MODEL)

\.oldmodel: $(if $(shell echo '$(MODEL)' | cmp $@ 2>/dev/null), phony,)
    @if [ -z "$(MODEL)" ]; then echo "error: MODEL is not set" && exit 1; fi
    echo '$(MODEL)' > $@

clean::
    rm -rf $(MODEL)
    rm -f .oldmodel
```

The `stuff_to_do` is your rule where you use the `$(MODEL)` variable.
Note, the prerequisites for `.oldmodel` rule is either a `phony` or empty depending on equality of `.oldmodel` file contents and `$(MODEL)`. This `phony` is taken as some non-existent file/rule, so when `phony` is there it causes the `.oldmodel` to be rebuilt.

Comment: Yes, checking for `model not set` I think can be moved out of recipe to another `ifeq`

Comment: big project has tens of build targets, every target should depends .oldmodel, this is the disadvantage of your code.